# Removing duplicates from a v-for list in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm trying to sort my list of notes by category. I have multiple notes in a single category, so `v-for` returns the assigned note category multiples times in the list.

I understand that I should use a computed property to filter the list, but I've experimented with the one below, `sortedCategories`, and can't seem to get it working.

Perhaps also relevant, I'm using Vue2 filters to sort the list alphabetically currently. After I get the list working without duplicates the next step is to be able click on the category and pull up all the notes in that particular category.

My code is:

```
<template>
  <div class="notebook">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
      </div>
    </nav>
    <ul>
      <!--
      <li v-for="(page, index) of pages" class="page" v-bind:class="{ 'active': index === activePage }"  @click="changePage(index)" v-bind:key="index">
        <div>{{page.category}}</div>
      </li>
      -->
      <li v-for="(page, index) of orderBy(pages, 'category')" class="page"
        v-bind:class="{ 'active': index === activePage }" v-bind:key="index">
        <div>{{ page.category }}</div>
      </li>
      <li class="new-page">Add Page +</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'
  Vue.use(Vue2Filters)

  export default {
    name: 'Notebook',
    props: ['pages', 'activePage'],
    mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],
    computed: {
      sortedCategories() {
        return this.categories.filter(function (category, position) {
          return this.pages.indexOf(category) == position;
        });
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changePage(index) {
        this.$emit('change-page', index)
      },
      newPage() {
        this.$emit('new-page')
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display a sorted list of unique `category` strings, you could easily do this with vanilla JavaScript:

1. Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on `pages[]` to group the array entries by `category`, where duplicate categories would overwrite the previous ones (thereby removing duplicates).
2. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on result #1 to get the array entries.
3. Use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on result #2 to sort the array by `category`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    pages: [
      { id: 1, category: 'Technology' },
      { id: 2, category: 'Sports' },
      { id: 3, category: 'Business' },
      { id: 4, category: 'Health' },
      { id: 5, category: 'Technology' },
      { id: 6, category: 'Health' },
      { id: 7, category: 'Technology' },
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    sortedCategories() {
      const cats = this.pages.reduce((p,c) => {
        p[c.category] = c
        return p
      }, {})
      return Object.values(cats).sort((a,b) => a.category.localeCompare(b.category))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="cat of sortedCategories" :key="cat.id">
      <div>{{ cat.category }}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`computed` should be a top-level key in your exported Object; right now it's a child of `methods`. Try moving it up one level:

```js
export default {
        name: 'Notebook',
        props: ['pages', 'activePage'],   
        mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],    

        computed: {
            sortedCategories() {
                return  this.pages.filter(function(page, position) {
                    return this.pages.indexOf(page.category)  == position; 
                });
            }
        }

        methods: {
          changePage (index) {
            this.$emit('change-page', index)
          },
        
          
          newPage () {
            this.$emit('new-page')
          },
         
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I moved it up and still no luck. I feel like my syntax or approach is off based on some of the computed property examples I've looked at. I've seen some use the name of the computed property near the v-for output to get the correct result, but I'm not certain how to do that considering I'm using orderBy on {{ page.category }} to get the list output in ABC order. Again, this is all new and I'm might not even be close. I'll update the code with the current attempt.